# Django App (treeio) error on PDF Generation

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pdf-generation, virtual-machine

This is the error which I am getting when I generate the PDF for any page... Any suggestion what it is?

I get this error each time I press the button of PDF generate it gives a file and then give 500 Error if I make DEBUG = FALSE if DEBUG = TRUE following error arises...

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://example.com/sales/product/view/76.pdf

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.markup',
'django_websocket',
'django.contrib.messages',
'treeio.account',
'treeio.core',
'treeio.core.api',
'treeio.core.search',
'treeio.documents',
'treeio.events',
'treeio.finance',
'treeio.identities',
'treeio.infrastructure',
'treeio.knowledge',
'treeio.messaging',
'treeio.news',
'treeio.projects',
'treeio.reports',
'treeio.sales',
'treeio.services',
'dajaxice',
'dajax',
'coffin',
'captcha',
'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'treeio.core.middleware.user.AuthMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'treeio.core.middleware.user.LanguageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',
'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
'treeio.core.middleware.user.SSLMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'treeio.core.middleware.chat.ChatAjaxMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'treeio.core.middleware.modules.ModuleDetect',
'minidetector.Middleware',
'treeio.core.middleware.user.CommonMiddleware',
'treeio.core.middleware.user.PopupMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "/treeio/treeio/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  121.                             response = middleware_method(request, e)
File "/treeio/treeio/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/treeio/treeio/core/decorators.py" in wrap
  48.                         return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/treeio/treeio/core/decorators.py" in wrap
  124.                 response = f(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/treeio/treeio/sales/views.py" in product_view
  674.                               context_instance=RequestContext(request), response_format=response_format)
File "/treeio/treeio/core/rendering.py" in render_to_response
  154.         f = codecs.open(source, encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py" in open
  878.     file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)

Exception Type: IOError at /sales/product/view/76.pdf
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/treeio/treeiobbaffc6da2ff9d79dbdbe7012437c4c0.html'
```

Comment: The application does not have the proper permissions to access the files.

Comment: How can I give that permission?